# error in cycle for on a json object

Tags: java, php, android, json

In my android project, I have an activity in which I want to obtain data from database using a PHP script. I manage the result of the script in this line :

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

I created the jsonObject :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

I print this line and get: {"id":"1"}{"id":"2"}{"id":"3"}

But when I do this:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    array[i] = "ID : "+jsonObject.getString("id");
}
```

I obtain "id : 1" three times, so I think there are some errors in the cycle..

the code of script php is here :

```
#Get the first row of the results 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($data)) {
      #Build the result array (Assign keys to the values) 
      $result_data = array( 
        'id' =>$row[0], 
       );
   #Output the JSON data
   echo json_encode($result_data);
```

Comment: there are no errors in the cycle..your implementation is wrong

Comment: how jsonObject created from result string?

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

Comment: how do you print the json and get that line?

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    jsonObject=array[i];
    String s = "ID : "+jsonObject.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: And overwrite s every loop?

Comment: no just an idea that you get the value in s. use it as you want to use it

Comment: when i write jsonObject=array[i]; i have this error : "cannot convert from String to JSONObject"

Comment: post your complete code. where you initialized  array from result?

Comment: array is not a json object..it's a normal string array

Answer (score 0):

```
 {"id":"1"}{"id":"2"}{"id":"3"}
```

is no valid code for a single JSON object - see here: [JSON syntax](http://json.org/).

I can only guess what you try to achieve, but I would guess your intention is to have a JSON array with 3 objects, each having an "id" value. The JSON code for such a structure should look like this:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]
```

If you can make "EntityUtils.toString(entity)" to return the above JSON code, the following loop should also work:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("ID : "+jsonObject.getString("id"));
}
```

**edit**

On a side note: I believe you get the result you describe, because when you call

```
 new JSONObject(result);
```

where the result is a String that consists of

```
{"id":"1"}{"id":"2"}{"id":"3"}
```

then most likely JSONObject stops parsing the JSON code after the first right brace without throwing a parse exception. So it actually only parses the *first* JSON object and because of this you get "id : 1" three times. Personally I would consider this behavior a bug, so consider reporting it.

Comment: i tried but i received this error : "Value {"id":"1"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Comment: Ok, my bad - I edited my answer so it should be more helpful.